# Is passing by reference to thread here bad practice?

Tags: c++, multithreading

This is the code listening from one C++ book.

```
void edit_document(std::string const& filename)
{
    open_document_and_display_gui(filename);
    while(!done_editing())
    {
        user_command cmd=get_user_input();
        if(cmd.type==open_new_document)
        {
            std::string const new_name=get_filename_from_user();
            std::thread t(edit_document,new_name);
            t.detach();
        }
        else
        {
            process_user_input(cmd);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see `edit_document` function can run other thread by itself. But the thread entry function takes filename as a const reference. Is it wrong in this case? Consider example when the new thread gets blocked in some way and `new_name` variable is actually destroyed and some garbage value is read. Is it possible in this case?

Comment: Please, don't post images, but the written code!

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread - look at the "Notes" section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with having a thread function that takes its argument by reference. The constructor for `std::thread` doesn't forward its arguments by reference; it **copies** the arguments that are passed to it. So, internally, when you create a thread with

```
std::thread t(edit_document, new_name);
```

it, in effect, generates code that spins up a thread which does this:

```
std::string first_arg(new_name);
edit_document(first_arg);
```

and `first_arg` lives until after `edit_document` returns. (Don't take that code literally -- the actual implementation is much more subtle. The constructor for `std::thread` won't return until `first_arg` has been constructed, so there's no risk that `new_name` will go away before the copy has been made)

You have to go out of your way to pass an actual reference to the thread function. That's what [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) does:

```
std::thread t(edit_document, std::cref(new_name));
```

If you do that, of course, you have to be sure that the lifetime of `new_name` will be longer than the thread. That's not common, for obvious reasons.